# Clickhouse . Distinct для одного столбца

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Я хочу получить уникальные значения из столбца «value» из stage1.table2 и сделать join к на stage0.table1. Но проблема в том, что stage1.table2 содержит неуникальные значения в столбце «value». Как мне нужно изменить мой скрипт, чтобы получить уникальное значение из таблицы stage2.table2 ? Так же отмечу, что столбец «time» и столбец «name» также не имеют уникальных значений. мне нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
SELECT  DISTINDT value , time  <- но DISTINCT должен быть применён только к value
FROM stage1.log table2
WHERE time >= '2022-06-30 11:30:00' AND time <= '2022-06-30 11:31:00'
AND name = 'Andy'
```

Полный скрипт:

```
SELECT  value, (toFloat64(table1.time) - toFloat64(table2.time))  AS time_delta
FROM stage0.log table1 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    time,
    value
FROM
(
    SELECT  value , time
    FROM stage1.log table2 
    WHERE time >= '2022-06-30 11:30:00' AND time <= '2022-06-30 11:31:00'
    AND name = 'Andy'
)) table2
    ON table2.value = table1.value 
WHERE
    time >= '2022-06-30 11:30:00' AND time <= '2022-06-30 11:31:00' 
    AND name = 'Andy'
ORDER BY time
```

результат:

```
value        time
51167477    -0.10901069641113281     <- here a problem
51167477    -0.10904145240783691     <- here a problem
51167477    -0.10900068283081055     <- here a problem
51167477    -0.10903143882751465     <- here a problem
51167478    -0.10303143882751465
```

Ожидаемый результат  :

```
value        time
51167477    -0.10901069641113281     
51167478    -0.10303143882751465
```

Comment: *Ожидаемый результат* Осталось объяснить, по какому критерию `-0.10901069641113281` оставлено, а остальные три значения проигнорированы.

Comment: до первого совпадение в таблице. Тоесть как только  мы встретили в таблице value = 51167477   для этой записи забираем time, дубликаты значений 51167477 которые мы дальше можем встретить в таблице игнорируются

Comment: Нет "первого" (как и "последнего", "второго", "дальше" и пр.), пока не указана сортировка, обеспечивающая уникальность сортируемых данных.

Comment: Мы идём по таблице встречаем value = 51167477 , у него time 2022-06-30 11:30:22.029 , всё следующие value 51167477 с другим time нас не интересуют. Думаю что можно брать наименьшее время из подзапроса: 

    SELECT  value , time
    FROM stage1.log table2 
    WHERE time >= '2022-06-30 11:30:00' AND time <= '2022-06-30 11:31:00'
    AND name = 'Andy'
   ORDER BY time

Comment: *Мы идём по таблице встречаем value = 51167477* Ни о чём. *можно брать наименьшее время* Если сортировка по времени обеспечивает уникальность - такой критерий подойдёт. Clickhouse знает про CTE и оконные функции? если да- использовать. Иначе - трахаться с подзапросами.

Comment: оконные функции поддерживаются но не все 
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions/
про CTE знает

Comment: Ну чё, CTE есть, ROW_NUMBER есть... выборка первой записи из группы - по-моему, вообще первое, что учат делать при знакомстве с CTE и оконными функциями.